# JS through2 Arrow function this.push()

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, lexical-scope

I have a problem with lexical binding in JavaScript.
This is my code:

```
.pipe(through.obj((url, enc, done)=>{
        if(!url) return done();
        request.head(url, (err, response)=>{
            this.push(url + ' is ' + (err ? 'down' : 'up') + '\n');
            done();
        });
    }))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.push is not a function
```

But when I use es5 function syntax like `function(url,enc,done){...}`:

```
.pipe(through.obj(function(url, enc, done){
        if(!url) return done();
        request.head(url, (err, response)=>{
            this.push(url + ' is ' + (err ? 'down' : 'up') + '\n');
            done();
        });
    }))
```

then my code works well.

In this case, **how can I use this.push() with the Arrow Function?**
I know about Arrow Function's lexical binding, but I have no idea about using `this`.

Thanks for reading my text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in the former case, your `this` is pointing to `window` object. That's why you're getting the error.

`arrow` functions  don't provide their own `this` binding (they retain the this value of the enclosing lexical context)

> In arrow functions, this retains the value of the enclosing lexical
>   context's this. In global code, it will be set to the global object:
>
> var globalObject = this; var foo = (() => this); console.log(foo() ===
>   globalObject); // true

Check this out [MDN-this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) particularly **Arrow functions** Section